# NDsolve for No-Linear system getting "not a list of number"

Tags: differential-equations

I want to solve this No-Linear equation system:

$1.2 (562500 + 1.2(r(t)^2 + 40^2 + 2r(t)40Sin(\phi(t)))) \phi(t)'' + 
  1030400\phi'(t) + 0.41\phi(t) =2Sin (4 t)$

$r''(t) - 0.7*9.8Cos(\phi(t)) + 9.8 Sin(\phi(t)) =0$

With these Initial conditions $r(0)=r'(0)=\phi(0)=\phi'(0)=0$. On the other hand, when $r(t)>1$ the value of $r(t)$ must be equal to $1$ or when $r(t)<-1$, $r(t)$ must be equal to $-1$. So, i use NDsolve to try to get numerical solution and plot but i recieve the following error:

```
NDSolve::nlnumThe function value {0.,1.47644*10^-6 (0. +0.000239388 Sin),0.000205275,6.86}
is not a list of numbers with dimensions {4} at {t,phi[t],(phi^\[Prime])[t],r[t],(r^\[Prime])[t]} = \
    {0.0000299235,0.,0.,0.,0.000205275}
```

I do not know what is wrong, the code used is below:

```
sol = NDSolve[{1.2 (562500 + 
    1.2*(r[t]^2 + 40^2 + 2*r[t]*40*Sin[phi[t]])) phi''[t] + 
 1030400*phi'[t] + 0.41*phi[t] == 2*Sin (4 t),
r''[t] - 0.7*9.8*Cos[phi[t]] + 9.8 Sin[phi[t]] == 0, 
  phi[0] == r[0] == phi'[0] == r'[0] == 0, WhenEvent[r[t] < -1, r[t] -> -1], WhenEvent[r[t] > 1, r[t] -> 1]}, {r[t], phi[t]}, {t, 0, 20}]


Plot[r[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 20}]
```

[image]

Comment: You have a simple typo: "Sin (4 t)" should read "Sin [4 t]"

Comment: I am blind... Thank you for the answer. After I do the change the values of "r" are bigger than the statement i putted in NDsolve (WhenEvent statement) Why this variable is taking bigger values in spite of writting that r(t) must be between -1 and 1?

Answer (score 0):

There is a misunderstanding here. `r[t] > 1` means the time when r[t] crosses 1 from below and not when r[t] is larger than 1. Look this up in the manual, it is a bit confusing.

To do what you want you could define a piecewise function like:

```
sol = NDSolve[{1.2 (562500 + 
        1.2*(r[t]^2 + 40^2 + 2*r[t]*40*Sin[phi[t]])) phi''[t] + 
     1030400*phi'[t] + 0.41*phi[t] == 2*Sin [4 t], 
   r''[t] - 0.7*9.8*Cos[phi[t]] + 9.8 Sin[phi[t]] == 0, 
   phi[0] == r[0] == phi'[0] == r'[0] == 0, 
   WhenEvent[r[t] < -1, r[t] -> -1], 
   WhenEvent[r[t] > 1, {r[t] -> 1, tend = t, "StopIntegration"}]
   }, {r[t], phi[t]}, {t, 0, 20}]
fun[t_] = 
 Piecewise[{{Evaluate[r[t] /. sol[[1, 1]]], t < tend}, {1, True}}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[fun[t], {t, 0, 20}]
```

[image]